# Why does bash behave different by only changing the row how the parsers are called?

Tags: bash, head, tail

I've stumbled about an interesting point in a command on bash and I can't imagine why the difference happened.
And sorry, I did not perform any search on google, archives and so on - because I've just NO idea what to search for...

Here is some test data for my Problem: http://nopaste.info/fdec0d967d_nl.html
Here the two prompts and the different output - what I am intending to do is to see begin and end of the example data:

```
2014/10/09 14:49:01 HilgenbF ~/working_files/_temp$ cat test.txt | ( head -n 10; tail -n 10 )
        Started at         : Samstag, 4. Oktober 2014, 23:22:43
        Started at         : Donnerstag, 2. Oktober 2014, 15:18:29
        Started at         : Samstag, 27. September 2014, 23:22:38
        Started at         : Montag, 22. September 2014, 21:00:58
        Started at         : Samstag, 4. Oktober 2014, 09:03:38
        Started at         : Samstag, 27. September 2014, 11:28:32
        Started at         : Samstag, 20. September 2014, 10:31:31
        Started at         : Samstag, 13. September 2014, 10:33:12
        Started at         : Samstag, 6. September 2014, 10:03:59
        Started at         : Montag, 1. September 2014, 09:01:33
        Started at         : Samstag, 13. September 2014, 23:23:16
        Started at         : Samstag, 4. Oktober 2014, 23:22:42
        Started at         : Dienstag, 30. September 2014, 18:45:10
        Started at         : Samstag, 27. September 2014, 23:22:38
        Started at         : Samstag, 20. September 2014, 23:30:08
        Started at         : Samstag, 4. Oktober 2014, 23:22:42
        Started at         : Mittwoch, 1. Oktober 2014, 10:09:00
        Started at         : Samstag, 27. September 2014, 23:22:38
        Started at         : Sonntag, 21. September 2014, 10:26:58
        Started at         : Montag, 22. September 2014, 09:10:42
2014/10/09 14:49:05 HilgenbF ~/working_files/_temp$ cat test.txt | ( tail -n 10; head -n 10 )
        Started at         : Samstag, 13. September 2014, 23:23:16
        Started at         : Samstag, 4. Oktober 2014, 23:22:42
        Started at         : Dienstag, 30. September 2014, 18:45:10
        Started at         : Samstag, 27. September 2014, 23:22:38
        Started at         : Samstag, 20. September 2014, 23:30:08
        Started at         : Samstag, 4. Oktober 2014, 23:22:42
        Started at         : Mittwoch, 1. Oktober 2014, 10:09:00
        Started at         : Samstag, 27. September 2014, 23:22:38
        Started at         : Sonntag, 21. September 2014, 10:26:58
        Started at         : Montag, 22. September 2014, 09:10:42
```

I know i could simply use the first working example, but I am really curious about how bash works :)

Thanks to all!
Florian

Comment: Wow - thx a lot to @chepner - that is fast :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/26278987/4091332

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tail -n 10` doesn't just consume the last 10 lines of its input; it consumes *all* of it in order to find what the last 10 lines are. Thus, in the second example, there is nothing left for the `head` command to read.

In the first example, `head` doesn't need to read the whole input, because it can stop reading as soon as it has read enough to output the first ten lines. However, there is also no guarantee that `head` reads *only* what it outputs. For example, `head -c 5` would output only the first 5 characters, but it may need to read at least one full line of more than 5 characters to find them.